# Change font of tabs, fontFamily not working

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.forms, tabs

I have an issue defining a custom font for tabs in my Xamarin.Forms app (on android).

The Tabbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabbarTitleText"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" >

  <!--<TextView
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:id="@+id/tabbar_title" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

I tried to put a textview but doesn't compile.

The style i created in styles.xml is applied except for the fontFamily property

```
<style name="TabbarTitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">fonts/Futura Book.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
```

Are all parameters correct? Especially **parent=**

If i use a custom renderer, it doesn't work because there is no child element to detect in TabLayout.

For my Toolbar it works because the TextView receive the custom render parameters.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                            
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/MyActionBar"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background_bar"
    android:elevation="3dp">

  <TextView
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
```

.

```
public class MyToolBarRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public MyToolBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        private Support.Toolbar _toolbar;

        public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
        {
            base.OnViewAdded(child);

            if (child.GetType() == typeof(Support.Toolbar))
                _toolbar = (Support.Toolbar)child;
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            var page = this.Element as NavigationPage;

            if (page != null && _toolbar != null)
            {
                Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/Futura Book.ttf");

                TextView title = (TextView)_toolbar.FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar_title);
                title.SetText(page.CurrentPage.Title, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                title.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            }

        }

    }
```

All my views are NavigationPages, not any TabbedPage.

In App.xaml.cs i have this

```
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
```

Then in MainPage

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    centerPage = new NavigationPage(new Center_Main())
                    {
                        Title = TitleCenter
                    };
                     ......
                    break;

                default:
                    centerPage = new Center_Main()
                    {
                        Title = TitleCenter
                    };

                    rightPage = new Right_Main()
                    {
                        Title = TitleRight
                    };

                    .......
                    break;
            }
```

Then every xaml is a ContentPage. I basically created a Master Detail project at beginning.

Comment: By `All my views are NavigationPages, not any TabbedPage.`, what do you mean? I usually use `NavigationPage` like this: `NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage());`, could you please show the code (both c# and .xaml)about your `NavigationPage`?

Comment: Updated end of my post, tell me if you need more info